# Animate UITableViewCells to new position AFTER deletion animation is complete

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've got a UITableView that allows the user to delete rows in it by swiping them left (very much like the app Clear). My issue is that all the UITableViewCells below the one being deleted animate up to their new frames while the animation for the deleted cell is happening. I want it to happen **after** the animation for the deleted cell finishes.

My code:

```
//Starts updating the table
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setAnimationDuration:JTTableViewRowAnimationDuration];
[CATransaction setCompletionBlock: ^{
    [self.spenderTable reloadData];
}];
[tableView beginUpdates];
if (state == JTTableViewCellEditingStateLeft)
{
    [self.list.spendrItems removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //!!Animation happens here!!
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
}

[tableView endUpdates];
[CATransaction commit];

[tableView performSelector:@selector(reloadVisibleRowsExceptIndexPath:) withObject:indexPath afterDelay:JTTableViewRowAnimationDuration * 2];
```

Im also using [this great UITableView](https://github.com/jamztang/JTGestureBasedTableViewDemo).

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this figured out....for anyone else interested. You can go two ways with:

**Approach #1 (Wrap in animation block):**

```
[UIView  animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
        [[(JTTransformableTableViewCell *)[self.spenderTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] contentView] setX:-320];
    }completion:^(BOOL done){
        [self.list.spendrItems removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    }];
```

Remember to manipulate the datasource in the completion block to avoid an internal consistency exception.

**Approach #2 (inherit from UITableView):**

Override the animation like so:

```
- (void)insertRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation{
 for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in indexPaths)
 {
     UITableViewCell *cell = [self cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell setFrame:CGRectMake(320, cell.frame.origin.y, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height)];

    [UIView beginAnimations:NULL context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [cell setFrame:CGRectMake(0, cell.frame.origin.y, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height)];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

}